When using torch snake_game is moving in a cirlce and not collecting food/reward. How do I fix this?
So I have a game of snake made in pygame where the snake starts off in the middle and grows bigger after collecting the food.
import pygame
import random
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)

class Direction(Enum):
    RIGHT = 1
    LEFT = 2
    UP = 3
    DOWN = 4

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')

# RGB colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (200, 0, 0)
BLUE1 = (0, 0, 255)
BLUE2 = (0, 100, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

BLOCK_SIZE = 20
SPEED = 10

class SnakeGameAI:
    def __init__(self, w=640, h=480):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.direction = Direction.RIGHT
        self.head = Point(self.w // 2, self.h // 2)
        self.snake = [self.head,
                      Point(self.head.x - BLOCK_SIZE, self.head.y),
                      Point(self.head.x - (2 * BLOCK_SIZE), self.head.y)]
        self.score = 0
        self.food = None
        self._place_food()
        self.frame_iteration = 0
        return self.get_state()

    def _place_food(self):
        while True:
            x = random.randint(0, (self.w - BLOCK_SIZE) // BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
            y = random.randint(0, (self.h - BLOCK_SIZE) // BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
            self.food = Point(x, y)
            if self.food not in self.snake:
                break

    def play_step(self, action):
        self.frame_iteration += 1
        self._move(action)
        self.snake.insert(0, self.head)

        reward = 0
        done = False
        if self.is_collision() or self.frame_iteration > 100 * len(self.snake):
            done = True
            reward = -10
            return self.get_state(), reward, done

        if self.head == self.food:
            self.score += 1
            reward = 10
            self._place_food()
        else:
            self.snake.pop()

        return self.get_state(), reward, done

    def is_collision(self, pt=None):
        if pt is None:
            pt = self.head
        if pt.x >= self.w or pt.x < 0 or pt.y >= self.h or pt.y < 0:
            return True
        if pt in self.snake[1:]:
            return True
        return False

    def _move(self, action):
        clock_wise = [Direction.RIGHT, Direction.DOWN, Direction.LEFT, Direction.UP]
        idx = clock_wise.index(self.direction)

        if np.array_equal(action, [1, 0, 0]):  # Move straight
            new_dir = clock_wise[idx]
        elif np.array_equal(action, [0, 1, 0]):  # Turn right
            new_dir = clock_wise[(idx + 1) % 4]
        else:  # Turn left
            new_dir = clock_wise[(idx - 1) % 4]

        # Prevent the snake from reversing
        if (self.direction == Direction.RIGHT and new_dir == Direction.LEFT) or \
           (self.direction == Direction.LEFT and new_dir == Direction.RIGHT) or \
           (self.direction == Direction.UP and new_dir == Direction.DOWN) or \
           (self.direction == Direction.DOWN and new_dir == Direction.UP):
            new_dir = self.direction
        
        self.direction = new_dir

        x = self.head.x
        y = self.head.y
        if self.direction == Direction.RIGHT:
            x += BLOCK_SIZE
        elif self.direction == Direction.LEFT:
            x -= BLOCK_SIZE
        elif self.direction == Direction.DOWN:
            y += BLOCK_SIZE
        elif self.direction == Direction.UP:
            y -= BLOCK_SIZE

        self.head = Point(x, y)

    def get_state(self):
        head_x, head_y = self.head.x, self.head.y
        food_x, food_y = self.food.x, self.food.y
        direction = self.direction.value
        # Features: normalized distances and direction
        return np.array([
            (food_x - head_x) / self.w,
            (food_y - head_y) / self.h,
            direction / 4,
            len(self.snake) / ((self.w // BLOCK_SIZE) * (self.h // BLOCK_SIZE))
        ])


Then using pytorch and cuda, I tried to train the AI to play using q_learning:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import os
import numpy as np

# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

class Linear_QNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x

    def save(self, file_name='model.pth'):
        model_folder_path = './model'
        if not os.path.exists(model_folder_path):
            os.makedirs(model_folder_path)
        file_name = os.path.join(model_folder_path, file_name)
        torch.save(self.state_dict(), file_name)

class QTrainer:
    def __init__(self, model, lr, gamma, epsilon_start=1.0, epsilon_end=0.01, epsilon_decay=0.995):
        self.lr = lr
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon_start  # Initial exploration rate
        self.epsilon_end = epsilon_end  # Minimum exploration rate
        self.epsilon_decay = epsilon_decay  # Decay factor for epsilon
        self.model = model.to(device)  # Ensure model is on the correct device
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self.lr)
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    def get_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() < self.epsilon:
            # Explore: select a random action
            return np.random.randint(0, 3)  # Assuming 3 possible actions
        else:
            # Exploit: select the best action based on the model
            state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
            with torch.no_grad():
                q_values = self.model(state.unsqueeze(0))  # Add batch dimension
                return torch.argmax(q_values).item()

    def train_step(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
        next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
        action = torch.tensor(action, dtype=torch.long).to(device)
        reward = torch.tensor(reward, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
        done = torch.tensor(done, dtype=torch.float).to(device)

        if len(state.shape) == 1:
            state = torch.unsqueeze(state, 0)
            next_state = torch.unsqueeze(next_state, 0)
            action = torch.unsqueeze(action, 0)
            reward = torch.unsqueeze(reward, 0)
            done = (done, )

        pred = self.model(state)
        target = pred.clone()

        for idx in range(len(done)):
            Q_new = reward[idx]
            if not done[idx]:
                Q_new = reward[idx] + self.gamma * torch.max(self.model(next_state[idx]))

            target[idx][torch.argmax(action[idx]).item()] = Q_new

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = self.criterion(target, pred)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

        # Update epsilon (exploration rate)
        self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon_end, self.epsilon * self.epsilon_decay)


Finally I wanted to run parallel environments so that the model would train faster and not take hours to learn how to play. Here is main.py
import pygame
import numpy as np
import torch
from snake_game import SnakeGameAI
from q_learning import Linear_QNet, QTrainer

# Hyperparameters
INPUT_SIZE = 4
HIDDEN_SIZE = 256
OUTPUT_SIZE = 3
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
GAMMA = 0.9
NUM_EPISODES = 1000
NUM_ENVS = 1  # Adjust this for parallel environments if needed

# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (200, 0, 0)
BLUE1 = (0, 0, 255)
BLUE2 = (0, 100, 255)
BLOCK_SIZE = 20

class ParallelEnvManager:
    def __init__(self, env_class, num_envs):
        self.envs = [env_class() for _ in range(num_envs)]

    def reset(self):
        return np.array([env.reset() for env in self.envs])

    def step(self, actions):
        next_state, rewards, done = [], [], []
        for env, action in zip(self.envs, actions):
            state, reward, d = env.play_step(action)
            next_state.append(state)
            rewards.append(reward)
            done.append(d)
        return np.array(next_state), np.array(rewards), np.array(done)

    def close(self):
        pygame.quit()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    width, height = 640, 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Q-Learning')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    model = Linear_QNet(INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE).to(device)
    trainer = QTrainer(model, LEARNING_RATE, GAMMA)
    env_manager = ParallelEnvManager(SnakeGameAI, NUM_ENVS)

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    running = True
    episode = 0

    while running and episode < NUM_EPISODES:
        state = env_manager.reset()
        done = np.zeros(NUM_ENVS, dtype=bool)
        while not np.all(done):
            actions = [trainer.get_action(s) for s in state]
            next_state, rewards, dones = env_manager.step(actions)

            trainer.train_step(state, actions, rewards, next_state, dones)
            state = next_state

            # Update display
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            for env in env_manager.envs:
                # Draw snake
                for pt in env.snake:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE1, pygame.Rect(pt.x, pt.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE2, pygame.Rect(pt.x + 4, pt.y + 4, 12, 12))
                # Draw food
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, pygame.Rect(env.food.x, env.food.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))

            score_text = font.render(f"Episode: {episode} | Score: {env_manager.envs[0].score}", True, WHITE)
            screen.blit(score_text, (10, 10))
            pygame.display.flip()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    break

        episode += 1
        pygame.display.set_caption(f'Snake Q-Learning - Episode {episode}')

    env_manager.close()
    model.save('snake_model.pth')
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


So far I've tried to change q_learning, thinking that maybe the AI needed to explore more. I've deleted pycache so that the machine learning would start over based on the new q_learning algorithm. I updated torch.device in main.py to use cpu if cuda isn't available.
I am new to machine learning/AI/pytorch and found a video of a snake AI game. I wanted to make this game from scratch and allow parallel environments by making a custom parallel environment manager class and have a GUI so I could see the AI play the game and learn. I thought this would be a good starting program so I could tweak my code based off what I see on the GUI.
After hours of tweaking the code, I cannot figure out why the AI just moves in a circle and does not want to explore the map or even find the walls.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

The reward system is unbalanced, until it starts to improve I recommend you put a death reward on -300, for every step where it does nothing -1 and for every apple +100.
This should push you to move more at least at the beginning then you can remove the negative word at each step when it starts to improve.
def play_step(self, action):
        self.frame_iteration += 1
        self._move(action)
        self.snake.insert(0, self.head)

        reward = 0
        done = False
        if self.is_collision() or self.frame_iteration > 100 * len(self.snake):
            done = True
            reward = -300
            return self.get_state(), reward, done

        if self.head == self.food:
            self.score += 1
            reward = 100
            self._place_food()
        else:
            reward = -1
            self.snake.pop()

        return self.get_state(), reward, done

